# how do i check my local "mysql" server is working or not?

Tags: mysql, xampp

I'm new on Stack, not sure if i'm asking the que in right way, anyway im having trouble with my local 'mysql' server, cant be sure its working or not, can you help me guys how do i? thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use some tools like toad or other ,to test your mysql is okay or not

Comment: This question is very broad :-( But you could try to connect (`mysql -u root`) and issue some commands, like `show databases;`. If they work then MySQL is up and running.

Comment: Imagine yourself trying to answer a similar question asked by another user. Now, edit your question with the details you'd ask that user to provide (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Since it is quite a broad question i'll have to give a broad answer.
To keep things simple, you could download MySQL workbench and try connecting with that. If it fails it will either give you an error indicating where the issue lies or tell you out right that it cannot find the server.

Since you added xampp in your tags i'm assuming your using that. Typically xampp comes with a tool on windows for starting / stopping the services and a button to open PhpMyAdmin in your default browser, the tool looks like this...

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [cbsi.com](http://i.i.cbsi.com/cnwk.1d/i/tim/2012/10/01/Foreman_12753563_2196_x.jpg))</sub>

This will show you if the service is running.